# Resetting Galaxy S 3 to factory default ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-3, downgrade

I am a new Android user, and recently I have upgraded the default ROM of Samsung Galaxy S 3 to Jelly Bean MIUI ROM using [the steps mentioned at the International Business Times](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/articles/377350/20120825/update-galaxy-s3-i9300-android-jellybean-miui.htm).

Now I want to revert it back to default ROM but I am unable to do so.

Although the blog says

> If you want to return to your previous ROM for some reason, boot into
>   recovery (using the procedure explained in step 3), choose backup and
>   restore, then restore your previous ROM by selecting it from the list.

But I didn't find anything within the list.

I tried wipe data / factory reset but still not getting the default ROM.

What do I need to do to get back the default firmware?

Comment: Did you do the NANDroid Backup, as step 4 of that guide suggested? If so, did it complete successfully? It might have failed e.g. if there was not enough space left on your sdcard. BTW: A factory-reset will never revert to the previous ROM -- it just cleans up all user data, caches, etc.

Comment: Yes, I did so and there was about 7 gb of space left within my internal memory. I didn't noticed whether it was successful or not(may be you are right), and after that i did the factory reset, which i believe must have deleted the back-up

Comment: Nope, factory reset doesn't delete anything on the card. Your backups should be saved there in the `clockworkmod/backup/` directory. I had it once with not enough space left on the card and got no warning (although I saw it when checking those 0 byte files *before* I continued to the next step ;), hence that question. 7G should be more than enough, usually. My backups never exceeded 1GB. But you already found the only alternative (+1 from me) -- still you might want to look for those files, for the next time to know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround, Downloaded a firmware from http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/ and updated my galaxy s3 with that using odin. Upon first reboot my phone hangs showing only boot screen with samsung logo for about 2 hours, then I restarted phone in clockworkmod recovery did a wipe data / factory reset and then restarted the phone again, I got the default firmware back. Then connected the phone to pc using kies and upgraded the firmware.